# Pip is not installing anything

Tags: cmd, pip

Whenever i try to install anything through pip, nothing happens. When i type in the command for installing a module and press enter, Nothing happens and the next prompt shows up.

This command

```
C:Users\ABC>python -m pip install target-package
```

returns:

```
C:\Users\ABC>
```

How do i fix this ?
I am using Windows 10.
I couldn't find any working solution for this problem.
I have tried re-installing pip and upgrading pip but nothing works.

Comment: where python returns the file location but where  pip is returning this: could not find files for the given pattern(s)
Does this mean that pip isnt installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your output when you run `pip -V` and `python -V` commands in your cmd?

Comment: nothing.
Even though python is installed and pip is too, those commands don't do anything. The next prompt shows up.

Comment: So in that case the path variables are not set for python, you can the path variable, just go through the steps given here [link](https://www.configserverfirewall.com/windows-10/add-python-to-path-windows-10/)